# set current user to self-created User object in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, session

In Google App Engine, you can create User objects with any email adress. These accounts will just not be conected with a google account. Is there a way to set the current user to such a user, without rolling my own session management, or using sessions from webapp2?

Comment: I think you meant `User property` not `User object`, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#UserProperty

Comment: I mean this creating my own instances of this class:, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine [Users API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) support Google Account or OpenID identifier.

If you need something different you have to implement users management yourself (or using a third party library like webapp2.extras)